# Когда использовать CQRS на PHP?

Tags: php, mvc, архитектура, cqrs

Всем привет!

Кто писал или что знает про backend-приложения с использованием паттерна CQRS?

Когда стоит использовать его, а когда остаться на очередной модификации MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Выскажу свое мнение.

Наверно не правильно говорить что именно использовать. Можно использовать только модификацию `MVC`, можно только `CQRS`, а можно и то и то вместе. Это ведь всего лишь паттерн, проще говоря - идея.

Вопрос только в том, на сколько профитно использовать то или иное. Но в нашем случае, лично мое мнение, что про `CQRS` стоит забывать. Больше кода, больше компонентов, больше файлов, вот это увеличение ради того, чтобы сказать что ваше приложение соответствует паттерну `CQRS`? Я просто не знаю где соблюдение `CQRS на PHP` является преимуществом. Возможно где-то в узкоспециализированных местах, но это уже другая история.

Comment: "Не обязательно следовать полностью паттернам проектирования" Градди Буч)))) Извиняюсь, не правильно сформулировал вопрос - я просто рассатриваю CQRS на backend как дальнейшее развитие MVC с разделением логики на Запросы и Мутации(комманды). То есть нет смысла разбивать контроллер на две независмые части? А почему? Возможны проблемы при реализации сложной бизнес-логики из-за большого количества классов? Спасибо!

Comment: @O.O у `MVC` есть модификаций, которые более удачны. Как пример, сходу на ум приходит `HMVC`. Также стоит понимать что такое контроллер, разбирая его на 2 независимые части, суммарно это уже навряд-ли можно назвать контроллером.